# Writing to serial port embedded linux using fopen

Tags: linux, serial-port, fopen

Try writing to serial port embedded linux using fopen:

```
   void send(char * text) {
    FILE * output;
    output = fopen("/dev/ttyM0");
    if(output != NULL) {
      fputs(text, output);
      fclose(output);
    }
```

After about 4000 sends i get only null pointer. No ideas what's wrong.

Comment: I believe the way `/dev/ttyM0` is intended to be used is that you `open()` it once in your program and then always use the same file descriptor. Writing data using stdio to `/dev/ttyM0` looks a bit ugly IMO; I would use the `open()` and `write()` system calls.

Comment: Tried that as well. The same result. I open fd with open() then use write(). Half an hour. Sending stops :/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the open system call. fopen is Standard C Library call for buffered file IO.